# How do I specify an Chrome Extension icon (popup icon) for Retina Mac's

Tags: google-chrome-extension, retina-display

I found my icon (and many other icons) very ugly on Retina Macs.

Is there any way that I can specify a well-designed retina image as the popup icon?

Thanks!

Comment: Try specifying a 38x38 icon in the browserAction field.

Comment: @RobW current it's `"browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon_19.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Weibo Karma!"
   },` so how do you suggest me to add the 38 one in?

Comment: Specify a dictionary with 19 and 38. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create double-sized icon (76x76 pixels) and provide path to it in `manifest.json`:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "icon19x19.png",
        "38": "icon76x76.png"
    }
}
```

If you want to dynamically change icon via [`setIcon`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon), then you must call it with following params:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: {
        "19": "icon19x19.png",
        "38": "icon76x76.png"
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need `76x76 (@4x)`, `38x38 (@2x)` is just fine, and that's what's actually needed for retina display.